# Formatting the values returned by SOQL

Tags: soql

Talking strictly SOQL (and no Apex or Visualforce), is there a SOQL equivalent of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634561.aspx)?

I am trying to return an aggregated result (COUNT) onto a 3rd party UI wrapper over Salesforce. But SOQL returns something like 2409 and I would like it to return 2**,**409. A well formatted number (perhaps even a currency format if the aggregate is a sum of $$$).

Comment: No, it is not possible for the query to return anything other than the prescribed format. You are free to modify it as needed but you said no apex or vf so.....

Comment: You could use formulas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been addressed in the [Spring'16 release](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring_%252716/formatting):

```
SELECT amount, FORMAT(amount) Amt, convertCurrency(amount) editDate, FORMAT(convertCurrency(amount)) convertedCurrency FROM Opportunity where id = '12345'

SELECT FORMAT(MIN(closedate)) Amt FROM opportunity
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with currency field then use convertCurrency() in the SELECT statement of a SOQL query to convert currency fields to the user’s currency. This action requires that the organization is multicurrency-enabled like:
SELECT Id, convertCurrency(AnnualRevenue) FROM Account